# Geoserver WPS Time and Bounding Box Filtering

Tags: xml, geoserver

I want to create a wps execution with time and bounding box filtering. However Geoserver returns "Parameter cropShape is missing". How can I solve this problem? Thank you for your help.In Below WPS request Body.
for request "http://serverName:port/geoserver/wps?service=WPS"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><wps:Execute version="1.0.0" service="WPS" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0" xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs" xmlns:wps="http://www.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0" xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:wcs="http://www.opengis.net/wcs/1.1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0 http://schemas.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0/wpsAll.xsd">
  <ows:Identifier>gs:CropCoverage</ows:Identifier>
  <wps:DataInputs>
    <wps:Input>
      <ows:Identifier>coverage</ows:Identifier>
      <wps:Reference mimeType="image/tiff" xlink:href="http://geoserver/wcs" method="POST">
        <wps:Body>
          <wcs:GetCoverage service="WCS" version="1.1.1">
            <ows:Identifier>it.geosolutions:35SNB_TCL</ows:Identifier>
            <wcs:DomainSubset>
              <ows:BoundingBox crs="http://www.opengis.net/gml/srs/epsg.xml#32635">
                <ows:LowerCorner>525451.12 4150325.37</ows:LowerCorner>
                <ows:UpperCorner>529330.75 4153680.93</ows:UpperCorner>
              </ows:BoundingBox>
            </wcs:DomainSubset>
            <wcs:DimensionSlice>
            <wcs:Dimension>time</wcs:Dimension>
            <wcs:SlicePoint>2020-06-11T00:00:00.000‌​Z</wcs:SlicePoint>
            </wcs:DimensionSlice>
            <wcs:Output format="image/tiff"/>
          </wcs:GetCoverage>
        </wps:Body>
      </wps:Reference>
    </wps:Input>
  </wps:DataInputs>
  <wps:ResponseForm>
    <wps:RawDataOutput mimeType="image/tiff">
      <ows:Identifier>result</ows:Identifier>
    </wps:RawDataOutput>
  </wps:ResponseForm>
</wps:Execute>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick check of the `DescribeProcess` response shows that the process takes two inputs:

```
<Input maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1">
    <ows:Identifier>coverage</ows:Identifier>
    <ows:Title>coverage</ows:Title>
    <ows:Abstract>Input raster</ows:Abstract>
    <ComplexData>
       ...
```

and

```
<Input maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1">
    <ows:Identifier>cropShape</ows:Identifier>
    <ows:Title>cropShape</ows:Title>
    <ows:Abstract>Geometry used to crop the raster</ows:Abstract>
    <ComplexData>
      ...
```

However, you are only supplying one input so GeoServer is pointing out that the 2nd one (`cropShape`) is required and that you have not supplied it. You need a polygon to specify the shape you want to crop to.

If all you want is to extract a "cube" from the WCS then you don't need the WPS at all.

Comment: Hey Ian, Thanks for your reply. I want to crop an image mosaic with a polygon boundary. My image mosaic has time enabled. So I want to crop specific date of the mosaic. You are right I forget to add crop shape parameter. However if I add the crop shape, Geoserver responds an error in WCS doeesn't find the raster.

Comment: If this answers your current question you should accept it and then ask a new question which reflects the next problem